# Pyscript Elastic Search(elk enterprise) Connection Error

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, pyscript

Connection error message in firefox developer console(f12) belov. How can I connect Elastic Cloud from pyscript client. I simple connecting Pyscript CDN and importing Elastic Search library in python()

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />

<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

 - from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Matplotlib</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
      - from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    </py-env>
    </head>
    <body>
       <py-script>
        # Password for the 'elastic' user generated by Elasticsearch
        ELASTIC_PASSWORD = "LKQp5hTjR6KC5zTbFtHT2V9r"
        
        # Found in the 'Manage Deployment' page
        CLOUD_ID = " "
        
        # Create the client instance
        client = Elasticsearch(
            cloud_id=CLOUD_ID,
            basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD)
        )
        
        # Successful response!
        client.info()
        # {'name': 'instance-0000000000', 'cluster_name': ...}
        
        
 
      </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The Error**

```
Uncaught (in promise) PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
   
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected string_end, found 'elasticsearch'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)

 
    raise InvalidRequirement(
packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'elastics'": Expected string_end
    
    setTimeout handler*hiwire_call_bound pyodide.asm.js:14
    callPyObjectKwargs pyproxy.gen.ts:360
    callPyObject pyproxy.gen.ts:384
    wrapper pyodide.asm.js:14
    setTimeout handler*hiwire_call_bound pyodide.asm.js:14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration for `<py-env>` is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
<py-env>
  elasticsearch
</py-env>
```

Import elasticsarch like this:

```
<py-script>
 from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
 ...
```

However, Elastic Search is not a supported package. It relies upon the Python `Requests` and `ssl` packages, which are supported by browsers. The `Requests` package uses the operating system TCP Socket API. That API is not available in the browser. This is not a PyScript limitation, it is a security restriction in the browser for all applications.

The only solution is to modify Elastic Search to use browser-supported APIs such as the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).